# How to find if a SKSpriteNode is child of self?

Tags: swift

(Sorry for my english)

I have an array of SKSpritenode that is getting new item every 5 seconds and i need to add the new ones to the view so i do:

```
for sprite in spriteList{
   self.addChild(sprite)
}
```

But this is giving me a error because i am not only adding the new ones. So is there a way to do something like this:

```
for sprite in spriteList{
   if(detect if self do not already have this sprite){
       self.addChild(sprite)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SKNode` (from which `SKSpriteNode` is inherited from) has an attribute named `parent` which you can check. If it's `nil` your node has no parent.

The documentation for this is located here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/parent

```
if sprite.parent == nil {
  println("This node has no parent!")
}
```